# Replacing multiple unique IDs with login name from fact table

Tags: t-sql, where-clause, identifier

I have 2 tables, a table with 3 unique user IDs that all can be different from each other... And a fact table with matching user login_names. (all three IDs can be unique)

```
       Table:LIS_Results
   Prelim_Report_TechID   |    Final_Report_TechID   |   Final_Test_TechID
------------------------------------------------------------------------
           23                      175                       200

       Table:Glb_Users
UserID    |   Login_Name
------------------------
  23            Jdoe
 175            Dduck
 200            mtyson
```

If the IDs were all they same it would just be an INNER JOIN and ID=ID and select Login_Name...

How do I reference the fact table and output all Login_Names that match the IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select table.id1, fk1.name
     , table.id2, fk2.name 
  from table 
  join fk as fk1 
    on fk1.id = id1 
  join fk as fk2 
    on fk2.id = id2
```

Comment: Thank you Blam. I am new to TSQL and naming the JOINs to make them unique so I can pull them back into the SELECT statement was what I was missing.